# How to link/add models to each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm trying to add `idea(s)` to a `user`. So far I added `has_many` to my user and `belongs_to` to my idea. And I added a foreign key to User using:

`rails g migration Add_User_id_To_Ideas user_id:integer`

Now, how do I assign the idea to the specific user, when a user creates a new idea?
I tried to work parallel to [this example](http://guides.railsgirls.com/commenting), but I'm a bit stuck.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :ideas
end
```

**idea.rb**

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  # {attr_accessor :Status}
  enum status: [ :Draft, :Published]
end
```

Comment: You can do `current_user.ideas.create(idea_params)` in `IdeasController#create` method. If you can post the code for idea form and controller i can propose a detailed answer.

Comment: @Muhammad, you're always welcome to check it out http://pastebin.com/qJJ6JN31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do this, but I think the most straight forward way would be to save the user_id in the ideas controller create action.

```
# def create inside ideas_controller
@idea.user_id = current_user.id

if @idea.save
  # etc
```

Couple other options are a hidden field or before_save callback. Here's an example of passing through a hidden field. In your @idea form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

This will add user_id to the params being saved. Make sure that :user_id is whitelisted in the permitted params at the bottom of your ideas controller.

To permit `user_id` in `idea_params`:

```
def idea_params
  params.require(:idea).permit(:user_id, :also_add_other_params)
end
```

Comment: I tried adding this `<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>` to my form but that didn't work

Comment: Most straightforward to just set in controller...but do you have user_id in your permitted params at bottom of ideas controller?

Comment: My apologies, I thought it worked but I get this error https://i.imgur.com/Uha5dCz.png

Comment: Do you have a user_id column on your table?

Comment: Ok I'm so stupid, looks like I never actually ran the migrations command, so I ran it and it works..